# How to store images from Mysql result to a folder in other proyect

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am currently developing a web application that is going to be used only by the staff of researchers where I'm doing my internship.

The main porpuse of this web app is to change images and other values from another project.

Basically, it's an interface to configure the main project and the way they want me to do it is to store the selected images from Mysql into the folder where the main project recovers the images so when they launch that project it loads the new sets of images stored in this folder.

I have no code to show you because I'm still getting my head around it and can't t find anything similar enough.

Any idea is welcome! thank very much :)

Comment: what's the question, you know what you want to do, so  .. um do it.

Comment: the question is the title, i dont know how to store an image from mysql to a local folder

Comment: they are stored as blobs?

Comment: Yes they are stored as blobs, just need a way to retrive de images from mysql and dump them into the folder

Comment: For images over 100k, this is generally considered a bad idea. It's better to store images in a file server.

Comment: I know its not optimal but this webb app its going to be used by few people, so performance its not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

assuming `$the_blob` is the blob from your query, all you need is:

```
file_put_contents('/your/directory/file_name', $the_blob);
```

Comment: Nice! didnt knew that function, i will try it! thanks ill let you know how it went